# Conflicting label Foregrounds

Tags: c#, forms, colors, label

I've recently started to learn c#, and I started off by making a simple tic-tac-toe game, using labels and forms.

When I click on a label I want it to change background color and Foreground color.

Here is my code;

```
        public void LabelClick(Label lbl, int i)
    {
        if (strCurrPlayer == strPlayer1)
        {
            liP1Squares.Add(i);
            lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            lbl.Text = "X";
        }
        else
        {
            //Player2
            liP2Squares.Add(i);
            lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            lbl.Text = "O";
        }
        lbl.Enabled = false;
        SwapPlayer();
    }
```

However, when it's called, it sets the background color correctly, but the foregorund, i.e. text, changes from the red, (default) to black for player 1 instead of White, and Light Grey for player 2, instead of Black.

I was wondering if there are any fields within Label or Forms that change text color by default when the background color is changed. If not, what else could be making this change?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried NOT to disable the field, i.e. leave out `lbl.Enabled = false`?

Comment: That works, but I would quite like the labels to be disabled once they've been click. Is there any other functionality that would achieve the same thing? `lbl.Clickable = false` for example?

Comment: Please read my answer for a suggestion (which is very usable and common, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set your items on the label, you are disabling it by

```
lbl.Enabled = false;
```

This then causes the label to use the disabled-theme from Windows.

In order to change this behavior, you should turn to using **events** instead of direct methods.

Every label offers a `Click`-event that you can use to call a method once the label was clicked.
You can then remove the event-handler from `Label.Click` and you don't need to disable it.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) to learn about `Control.Click`-EventHandler

Comment: I have registered on Clicks, mouse in and mouse out events on all the labels constituting the 3x3 grid. The method above gets called by the on clicks. Is there a way to neatly remove all event handlers from a selected UI element? I've looked around SO, and all the methods seem slightly ham fisted.

Comment: Okay, then you only need to take off the event-handler after you clicked. Still, you should try to keep the "Microsoft"-way of using events, by (if necessary) creating `delegates` and using the `EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)`-notion. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) tutorial is a little old, but describes the method just fine.
Yes, by saying `EventXYZ = null` you remove all attached invokers from the list, this is valid only for events you created, for events of `Controls` you must stick with `Control.Event -= EventHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

remove `lbl.Enabled = false;` to see the changes

after you dissable control it will set the label background color to `SystemColors.Control` and foreground color to `SystemColors.GrayText`